# Creating .svg using Potrace producing negative trace of .png

Tags: svg, png

I'm trying to turn .png files with transparent backgrounds into .svg files using Mac version of [Potrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potrace) but they keep coming out negative.

For example, using this StackOverflow logo image:

[image: Original Image]

Performing the following steps via Terminal:

```
convert stackoverflow-4-xxl.png file.pnm
potrace file.pnm -s -o file.svg
```

produces the *negative* trace, as shown below:

[image]

I'm sure there's an obvious setting or parameter I can pass in to Potrace, but my knowledge is sadly lacking right now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I presume you are really trying to extract the alpha channel. Your start image actually has a white background which shows through in the transparent areas rather than the expected black. If you run this to make the background blue, you will see `convert logo.png -background blue -flatten result.png`.  You can do what I think you want in one line with `convert logo.png -alpha extract -negate pnm: | potrace - -s -o file.svg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this, not by getting the potrace settings right, but by inverting the color of **file.pnm** in Gimp just before calling **potrace file.pnm -s -o file.svg**.